# Ошибка с JS при запуске приложения на RoR (turbolinks.js.coffee)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Работаю с примером из книги, создаю приложение:

```
>>rails new demo
```

Добавляю контроллер и два метода:

```
>>rails generate controller Say hello goodbye
```

Запускаю сервер rails, перехожу на урл http://localhost:3000/say/hello и вместо нужной странички вижу ошибку:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

**Делаю все по книжке (Rails 4, Гибкая разработка веб-приложений).**

Answer (score 1):

На windows кофе скрипт нормольно не работает. Добавь в gem file вот эту версию:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Потом запусти

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

[Вот источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit)

Имхо. Хочешь норм разрабатывать, переходи на Убунту, не занимайся лишними действиями, которые тебя не приведут к профиту.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь все ли в порядке с отступами и синтаксисом в твоем coffee script файле. Еще как вариант - подключи только 1 безобидный coffee script файл с чем-то вроде console.log() или alert() внутри и попробуй запустить. Если запустится - значит разбирай твой coffee scipt файл построчно.

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил эту проблему с помощью установки **[node.js](https://nodejs.org/)** и перезагрузки компьютера.

Полное описание проблемы и решение(EN): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial/14118913#14118913